# Slow running cold water

Tags: water-pressure

My cold water tap in my bath has gone from fully running to a trickle.  I have taken off the tap bit but all seems ok.  Any suggestions please?

Comment: Is the plumbing on an outside wall? Are you in the area of the Polar Vortex experiencing unusually cold weather? Any chance the pipes could be freezing?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Is this happening on other nearby water sources? What  kind of control are we talking (two valves, single hot/cold valve)? A picture would really help...